# GTK+ or Qt under Windows

Tags: qt, gtk

I was wondering which one should I consider if I need the software to be used on both platforms, WIN and Linux and why?

Comment: Im looking more in how difficult also will be compiling under windows each of those? I know QT is fairly similar than compiling it under linux. Also which one will take longer time coding the same type of apps?

Comment: My answer, which for some reason was voted down, stated that compiling GTK on Windows is hard. Very time consuming. I don't recommend it. Qt is a 2 hour compile that usually has no troubles. Although distributing c++ compiled with visual studio 2005+ has its own issues.

Comment: What's wrong with the asker Mike? His avatar went gray.

Answer (score 25):

Packaging GTK and its dependencies on Windows is a full-time project in itself. Qt is much more easily distributed since it has no dependencies that do not come with Windows.

Qt has been cross platform from the start. GTK has not always been cross platform. Such fundamental decisions shape the overall design, and should be made before any code is written in my opinion.

I would comment more, but I'd be drifting into speculation, the above two things I know for certain.

Comment: There is an [all-in-one installer for PyGTK 2.24](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/). I tried it and works, and recent GTK versions seems to be much better and have native support on windows. What makes it comparable with Qt on windows.

Comment: Unless I love GTK on *nix, mostly because of its design.

Answer (score 14):

Both are good toolkits that have their advantages and disadvantages.

One difference is the implementation language.  Qt is in C++, and GTK+ is in C.  However GTK+ has bindings for many, many other languages (perl, python, C++, .NET, etc) so it's not a huge issue.

An Advantage of Qt is that it offers a bit broader range of functionality built in (xml, database access, network programming, openGL, etc).  GTK+ has basically all of these things within its orbit (e.g. libxml2, librsvg, libsoup, libgda, etc), but they're not as much of a single coherent package as Qt is.

My personal recommendation is to use [gtkmm](http://gtkmm.org/), the C++ bindings for GTK+.  It offers a more comfortable object-oriented language to program in, and it provides nearly the same native performance as using GTK+ from C.  (Disclaimer: I contribute to gtkmm).

Comment: And of course, now Qt is LGPL too.

Comment: I removed the outdated paragraph about the license.

Comment: Does GTK look native on Windows, however? Also doesn't it depend on X server? I've seen a port of Deluge on Windows, and it looked horrible.

Answer (score 5):

GTK+ you can use almost in all programming languages, in C++ (using gtkmm) in C (gtk+) in C# (with Gtk#) in Python (PyGtk). Behind GTK you have Mono Framework which is great implementation of .NET Framework for cross platform purposes. If you want to use Gtk# you have great IDE (MonoDevelop) with a very powerful gui designer. You can take a look at www.mono-project.org. But still depends what do you want to build, you are looking just gui toolkit, or the entire framework? And the logic behind signals/slots are the same in Gtk+ and Qt, but if you are using Gtk# they are transformed in the delegates/events paradigm.

Comment: If you're developing commercial software, you'd be a fool to use anything other than the base libraries, ie. GTK or Qt. Anything above that has no guarantee of maintenance or reliability. Generally speaking.

Comment: @Max PyGTK and GTK# are both supported for Gnome app development, so I would expect them to have a good level of support (equivalent to GTK+ itself).

Comment: Well then you're bound to be both upset and surprised when you find that isn't the case.

Comment: It is said that mono is not being actively developed. If mono is dying, so is GTK#.

Answer (score 5):

my $0.02:

I've used Qt off and on for the last 4 years, and it's hands-down my favorite toolkit of anything I've tried (Win32, MFC, Borland, Java, GTK).  I used GTK for a few weeks to try it out, and didn't like it.  Mostly that was because I think it's awkward to use C instead of C++ for GUI apps on a PC... I do embedded work too, and I'd never use C++ on an 8051, but for a big GUI app I much prefer it.  If you're going to try GTK, I'd suggest looking in to [GTKmm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gtkmm), although I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 4):

You might also consider wxWidgets. I have never used any of them but when I was looking over the cross-platform toolkits it was the one I had decided to try.

Answer (score 3):

They are both fine toolkits. I'd base my decision on the licensing. Qt requires that you pay for a license if you are using it in a commercial product wheras GTK does not.

Comment: Of course this is no longer true.

Comment: It is very much still true if you're doing anything commercial.

Answer (score 3):

Three additional points in favor of Qt:

1. Your project does *not* have to be GPL; there are many other open-source licenses available in the [Qt GPL Exception](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/license-gpl-exceptions.html), including BSD and LGPL.
2. Qt's default theme on Windows does a much better job of blending in than GTK's Wimp theme.
3. If you want to support Macs later, you'll have a much easier time with Qt.

Comment: GTK+ is supported on the Mac, or is at least getting there.

Comment: Qt is supported on Mac, Windows, Linux and other embeded plattforms in a reduced form

Comment: From Gtk.org: "GTK+ is licensed under the GNU LGPL 2.1 allowing development of both free and proprietary software with GTK+ without any license fees or royalties."

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer Qt. As today, Qt is Open-source and free under more permissive, LGPL license.
Qt is better ported for Windows and looks more native than GTK. Gimp on windows, for example, looks very strange, because most of its dialogs are not Windows dialogs. Qt can use native Window dialogs like Open/Save which makes it feel better as a framework. And yes, Qt is a framework, not only a GUI Widget. No, I am not advertising Qt here, as Qt have some strangeness for a windows user from development point of view, for example, Qt is Layout based while MFC / .NET are anchor based and Qt's Layout managers are sometimes strange. But if I have to choose between both GTK and Qt, I will select Qt. Also, now, Qt comes with very good IDE, Qt Creator, which is my default C/C++ IDE for all types of projects now (as Qt Creator can be used as such).

Answer (score 2):

Qt 5.0 has won the war. 
I'm not a huge fan of C++ (I prefer plain old C), but I must admit that the Qt framework is amazing.
Try to write a GUI program with GTK that runs on OSX, Linux, Windows (and soon iOS and Android) with native look-and-feel... Good luck !

Comment: Nowadays [Flutter](https://flutter.dev) is an interesting competitor in this area, with the advantage of supporting the Web as another target platform.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Qt because:

- It's cross-platform and and covers wide range of operating systems (including mobile)
- It is opensource and has a fast speed in getting better
- It has the a nice GUI designer and a very capable IDE (Qt Creator)
- The API design is excellent and easy to use
- It has a great documentation which is easy to read
- It has the Qt translation system which enables you to have a multilingual app
- The GUI layout system where the widgets resize themselves according to a layout makes everything much easier
- The QML gives you the power to create fantastic GUI with great graphics and animations
- It has great support for networking and connectivity(socket, SSL, www, IPC, ...)
- It has QTestLib for testing the code
- It has many language binding if you don't want to use C++