# Cross platform compatibility in C/C++ (porting a project from Java)?

Tags: java, c++, c, networking, cross-platform

I wrote a program in Java/JavaFX because I needed cross platform support. As I progressed, I needed to do some low level OS networking operations that aren't possible in Java. I started with Runtime.exec(), moved to JNA/JNI, and now I'm worried that maintaining OS compatibility for Java will end up being more work than just porting to a native applications.

What is the best way to do this?

I know GTK+ is supported by *nix and windows so I think I'll use that for my UI. How difficult is it going to be to maintain different versions of my application for each OS? Can you recommend a starting point for writing something that needs to be cross platform but still has low level OS access? I have a lot of Java experience (and a good amount of C++ with OpenGL) but I've never had to care about anything but Linux before.

*Alternatively, is there a good way to build raw packets, send ICMP pings, and do other low level networking tasks from Java?*

Comment: http://www.savarese.com/software/rocksaw/ ??

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. C++ itself is very portable, even more so than Java in some ways, but the standard library is minuscule in comparison. In C++ you often need to rely on third party or platform-specific libraries to do things like GUI as you've noticed.

Comment: someone mentioned a library to make it very easy for java code to invoke OS API. but I don't remember the name.

Comment: I wonder what do you mean by low level OS networking operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is pretty general, so I will list some best practices here. I can narrow things down, if you edit your question accordingly.

**1-** The most importing thing is the compiler and the build environment. This is probably trivial to choose, both **Clang** and **GCC** are supported on all major platforms. However, the build environment is a bit tricky. Just a single Makefile will not be good for all platforms. Instead, go for something like [**CMake**](http://www.cmake.org/) or [**SCons**](http://www.scons.org/). This will help you manage your source and generate appropriate makefiles on all systems easier.

**2-** You might want to build the same GUI on all platforms. In that case, you can use [**Qt**](http://qt-project.org/) or [**GTK+**](http://www.gtk.org/) as you mentioned.

**3-** File I/O. If you have a lot of File I/O, you might want to have a look at [**Boost File System**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

**4-** For all additional libraries you use, make sure they are supported on all platforms. In general, I suggest using libraries that are historically well maintained, like **Boost**.

**5-** Finally, hide platform specific code using the [PIMPL Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

If you want to go deeper in Cross Platform C++ programming, here is a good book: [Cross-Platform Development in C++: Building Mac OS X, Linux, and Windows Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032124642X).

Comment: Neither Clang nor GCC support Windows very well.

Answer (score 3):

Since your requirement for native code seems related to network packets, you may take a look at [JPCAP](https://github.com/mgodave/Jpcap). Note: there are two forks of JPCAP: the one hosted on SourceForge (package `net.sourceforge.jpcap.net`), that doesn't support sending, and the one I linked here (package `jpcap`, which was originally hosted at `http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii`). I think it will be enough for most "low level" network operations (including listening on promiscuous mode, sending non-IP datagrams, ICMP, etc).

Comment: Jpcap looks very intresting, but it hasn't been updated in 8 years and all the download links are broken. I mange to find the source code via the Fedora repos, but it won't compile under x86_64. Do you use Jpcap? Maybe you can help me out.

Comment: Interesting... I downloaded it by 2007, so I didn't know the links were dead. I edited my answer with a link to a version on github that looks as if it is the one with the sender (note that github's `jpcap/jpcap` is the same as sourceforge's one).

Answer (score 1):

Qt is probably the best choice for cross-platform GUI. I don't think GTK+ is a great choice if you want to target Windows (or Mac). However, maybe this has changed. It's been while since I last checked. Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199604/gtk-or-qt-under-windows).

Boost and Poco are both good cross-platform C++ libraries. They also both provide networking libraries (boost asio and Poco Net).

Sending ICMP ping requests is supported by both [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.icmp) and [Poco](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Net.ICMPClient.html).

I'm not sure if these libraries allow you to build your own Ethernet frames and IP packets though.

Answer (score 0):

It is more of design stuff,

1. Try to use cross platform libraries wherever it is possible (ex: boost)
2. Write platform specific code and write good abstraction layer on top of it.

ex: Windows/Signaling, Linux/Signaling,  Signaling 
      Here,

- **Windows/Signaling** is windows platform specific signaling code
- **Linux/Signaling** is Linux platform specific signaling code
- **Signaling** is platform abstraction layer, compile time we can decide the platform